# Profiling Tensorflow Estimators

Tags: python, tensorflow, profiling

I'm busy trying to profile the [tensorflow BERT code](https://github.com/google-research/bert) to see if it's fast enough for a particular use case.

I need to determine the speed of predictions. Now, as I understand, one would add a [profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/profiler/Profiler) or a `run_metadata` object to the `session.Run` options. However, BERT is using the new [Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/estimators) API.

How does one profile the Estimators? Is that possible?

**Update:**

The Tensorflow team showed me [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24428) that one could attach a `ProfilerHook` to an estimator:

```
hooks = [tf.train.ProfilerHook(save_steps=1, output_dir=model_dir)]
estimator.predict(..., hooks=hooks)
```

This produces a trace file, but the trace does not work.

```
Error : Couldn't create an importer for the provided eventData.
at Import.createImporter_ (chrome://tracing/tracing.js:1300:2071)
at addImportStage (chrome://tracing/tracing.js:1295:167)
at Task.run (chrome://tracing/tracing.js:2307:95)
at runAnother (chrome://tracing/tracing.js:2310:371)
at runTask (chrome://tracing/tracing.js:2286:57)
at processIdleWork (chrome://tracing/tracing.js:2291:116)
at window.requestIdleCallback.timeout (chrome://tracing/tracing.js:2284:81)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have used tf.estimator files of type timeline-.js will be created. load any of these timeline-.js in  chrome://tracing/ to see the trace file
You will find the timeline-.js files in the model directory.

Comment: that works +1, but where do you need to put these files so you can see them in tensorboard.